# Directions Side Bar in Windows 8 Maps Application?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm new to Windows 8 development. I want to implement something similar to the following in Microsoft Maps application for Windows 8:
In the maps app, when the user clicks on Directions menu item in the app bar, a side bar appears on the right.

How can I implement such a side bar ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no such control built-in in WinRT. The closest to what your looking for would be `SettingsFlyout` control from [Callisto](http://nuget.org/packages/Callisto). It's not ideal for this case, since it was designed to be used as settings flyout. Most notably you'd need to get rid of the back button which opens up the settings charm. You could try overriding the style or taking the control [source code](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Flyout/Flyout.cs) and modifying it.

It's really simple to use, though:

```
var flyout = new SettingsFlyout();
flyout.FlyoutWidth = SettingsFlyout.SettingsFlyoutWidth.Narrow;
flyout.HeaderText = "Flyout";

flyout.Content = new FlyoutControl();
flyout.IsOpen = true;
```

`FlyoutControl` would be a custom `UserControl` you want to display.